# Three.js clickable objects not clickable

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am attempting to turn 3D objects into clickable elements by using an array called objects[]; and a switch statement which accesses the userData of the object. Right now, the script runs with no errors yet the objects still aren't clickable. What am I missing?

```
  var container, stats;
        var camera, scene, raycaster, renderer;

        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2(),
            INTERSECTED;
        var radius = 100,
            theta = 0;

        init();
        animate();





        function createMesh(name, geometry, material) {

            var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
            object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
            object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

            object.scale.x = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
            object.scale.y = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
            object.scale.z = Math.random() * 2 + 1;

            object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
            object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
            object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

            object.userData = {
                URL: "http://www.google.com"
            };
            var objects = [];

            for (i = 0; i > objects.length; i++) {
                objects += i;
                objects.push(object);
            }
            scene.add(object);



            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    objects[i].userData = {
                        URL: "http://www.google.com"
                    };
                    break;
                case 2:
                    objects[i].userData = {
                        URL: "https://www.yahoo.com"
                    };
                    break;
            }


            object.name = name;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think your code qualifies as **minimal**. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also make sure the code can be run directly, either by making it a snippet, or providing a jsFiddle.

Comment: Your code  doesn't make much sense, did you write it? Which part of the code is supposed to make it clickable? Loop doesn't loop, `+=` on an array,

Comment: Yes, I am a bit of a newbie though. Sorry about that.

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger and step through the lines, there's too much not working (code doesn't make enough sense) for us to explain what is wrong. SO is not for you to ask for us to debug something. You should have debugged it already, but you don't understand its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var objects = [];

        // objects.length == 0
        // i is not greater than so nothing happens
        for (i = 0; i > objects.length; i++) {
            objects += i;
            objects.push(object);
        }
        scene.add(object);


        // i is still equal to 0 so nothing happens once again
        switch (i) {
            case 1: ...
            case 2: ...
```